# How can I set JSX to a variable so that I can optimize my code?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and working on a side project to understand it more. I have 3 conditionals that return the same JSX, I tried to set the JSX into a variable and display it but I keep getting an error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {restaurantCard})". My goal is to optimize my code and output my variable restaurantCard in each corresponding conditionals.

Here is my code:

```
  // Our JSX that shows our restaurant
  let restaurantCard = (
    <div className="game">
      <RejectButton handleRejectClick={handleRejectClick} />
      {/* Chooses a random restaurant to view in our remaining restaurants */}
      <Card 
        yelpResults={yelpResults[1]}
        // yelpResults={yelpResults[restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]]}
      />
      <ApproveButton handleApproveClick={handleApproveClick} />
    </div>
  )

  // Show Approve Route
  if (showApprove === true) {
    console.log('Approve Render')
    console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
    console.log(`Random Restaurant Index: ${restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]}`);
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <RejectButton handleRejectClick={handleRejectClick} />
        {/* Chooses a random restaurant to view in our remaining restaurants */}
        <Card 
          yelpResults={yelpResults[restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]]}
        />
        <ApproveButton handleApproveClick={handleApproveClick} />
      </div>      
    )
    // Show Reject Route
  } else if (showReject === true) {
      console.log('Reject Render')
      console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <RejectButton handleRejectClick={handleRejectClick} />
          {/* Chooses a random restaurant to view in our remaining restaurants */}
          <Card 
            yelpResults={yelpResults[restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]]}
          />
          <ApproveButton handleApproveClick={handleApproveClick} />
        </div>      
      )
  // If yelpResults does not have data for some reason this is our error handling content
  } else if (Object.keys(yelpResults).length === 0) {
    console.log('Error Handling')
    console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
    return (
      <div>
        Website was refreshed, you have to click "Home" and restart.
      </div>
    )
    // Our initial render, meaning no buttons were clicked and no error
  } else {
      console.log('Initial Render')
      console.log(`Restaurant Indexes: ${restaurantIndexes}`);
      return ({restaurantCard})
        // <div className="game">
        //   <RejectButton handleRejectClick={handleRejectClick} />
        //   {/* Chooses a random restaurant to view in our remaining restaurants */}
        //   <Card 
        //     yelpResults={yelpResults[1]}
        //     // yelpResults={yelpResults[restaurantIndexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurantIndexes.length)]]}
        //   />
        //   <ApproveButton handleApproveClick={handleApproveClick} />
        //   {restaurantCard}
        // </div>
      
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to remove the `{}` curly braces and see if it helps.

E.g,  `return restaurantCard;`

EDIT: As requested from the comments, curly braces have to be used only inside the JSX.

E.g,

```
const myName = "Kevin";

return <div>{myName}</div>;
```

Comment: Could you give a typical example when we need to use `{}`?

Comment: const myName = "Kevin" ;
return <div>{myName}</div>;

Answer (score 1):

You only need the curly braces around variables when they're nested *inside* JSX. When you're returning the restaurant card, that's just regular JS. So you can just have `return (restaurantCard)`

**EDIT:**

At @Subrato's request, here's a short example to try to help illustrate the point:

```
// This is a just a regular Javascript variable. No need for special curly braces
let restaurantName = "Mr Magoo's eatery";

// The restaurantCard variable itself is just a plain JS variable
// However, its CONTENTS are JSX
let restaurantCard = (
    <div className="restaurant__card">
        {restaurantName} // This is a variable inside JSX, so it needs curly braces
    </div>
)

// As mentioned above, restaurantCard itself is just a plain JS variable
// So we can return it as normal
return restaurantCard;
```

Comment: Could you give a typical example when we need to use `{}`?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik as asked, added a basic example of when variable values needs curly braces and when it doesn't